# Root pronunciation change when adding suffix

Tags: pronunciation

Can someone provide the proper academic terms and explanations for why we pronounce the roots of the following words differently:

> sociopath vs. sociopathy
>
> telepath vs. telepathy
>
> biographic vs. biography

And along the same lines, is it related in anyway to the same change that occurs in

> athlete vs. athletic
>
> episode vs. episodic

I was explaining the concept to my daughter and realized I had no backing other than "it sounds nicer" (which certainly they do) and would like something a little more solid.

EDIT: This is not merely asking why certain words are stressed where they are, but why suffixes and variations cause the *pronunciation* of certain words to change almost completely. So not simply the shift from U-ni-verse to to u-ni-VERS-i-ty, but the shift from tuh-LEH-puh-THY to TEL-uh-PATH.

I've updated the title to reflect it's the change in pronunciation not simply the change in stress that I'm interested in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "omnipotent" stressed iambically?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249480/why-is-omnipotent-stressed-iambically), where it's pointed out that *It is very frequent, at least in BrE, that long Latin/Greek words are stressed on the third-last syllable.*

Comment: Many suffixes shift the stress forward one syllable; _-ic/-ical_ and _-ity_ are examples: _history/historic, hermit/hermetical, fraternize/fraternity_. Most of this is simple inheritance of the Latin stress rule, using suffixes that were already attached when the word was borrowed into English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers except sociopath doesn't emphasize the third-last syllable (nor does biographic) so it's not merely following a rule.

Comment: @Kyle Hale: It's a *tendency*, not a "rule" (but it does apply to all OP's examples - *sociopathy, telepathy, biography*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a pretty complicated topic.

The change in the pronunciation of the vowels can be considered a secondary effect of the change in stress. Changing the pronunciation of a vowel in an unstressed syllable is called "vowel reduction". In "telepath", the first syllable is stressed, so the vowel is pronounced as unreduced /ɛ/, whereas in "telepathy", the first syllable is unstressed, so the vowel is reduced to schwa /ə/.

In stressed syllables, single vowel letters can usually be pronounced at least two ways in English (one of the most notorious features of its spelling) but a complete account of the rules for vowel pronunciation in stressed syllables based on the context would be rather long and I don't think the examples really call for it. So the rest of this answer will just be about stress patterns.

In *sociopathy, telepathy* and *biography,* the stress is on the third-to-last or "antepenultimate" syllable. This is actually a fairly common position for stress in Latinate words, and "sociopathy" and "telepathy" belong to a particular subtype of words where this stress shift is common: compounds of Greek roots ending in *-y,* where the second element ends in  a single consonant. I know that explanation is a bit complicated, so here are a few examples: *geology, geography, astronomy* and in general words ending in [*-logy, -graphy, -nomy,*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-are-words-ending-ology-onomy-ography-pronounced) -phony, -scopy.

Anther noun ending that causes stress to fall on the antepenult syllable is *[-ity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278084/a-rule-for-identifying-the-stressed-syllable-in-abstract-nouns-ending-in-ity-i).*

However, I don't know enough phonological theory to explain why this stress pattern is used in these words.

*Athletic, episodic* and *biographic* are examples of a rule that adjectives ending in the suffix *-ic* are stressed on the second-to-last syllable ([with some exceptions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303671/words-pronounced-with-stress-patterns-like-in-politics-lunatics-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Some people have tried to explain the *-ic* stress rule as resulting from the application  of the third-to-last rule by using certain abstract analyses of the structure of words, but I haven't yet seen an explanation along these lines that seemed convincing to me. (For example, Chomsky and Halle's *The Sound Pattern of English* (1968) argued that "-ic" words with stress on the second-to-last syllable have an underlying form with an extra syllable "al" that has been deleted; this is not entirely unmotivated as "ic" words do often coexist with "ical" words with "al" explicitly present, and there is a spelling rule by which adjectives ending in "ic" usually correspond to adverbs ending in "ically", but nevertheless it seems rather far-fetched. This analysis is mentioned by Erik Fudge in "English Word Stress: Basic Assumptions", a paper in *[Essays on the Sound Pattern of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=McUnAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=%22the+sound+pattern+of+English%22+ic&source=bl&ots=8vVapT5zPl&sig=nqoguOBTyZytCB4ANiupyD5dFWM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiixM-81d7YAhUMbawKHeagBmQQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=%22the%20sound%20pattern%20of%20English%22%20ic&f=false)* (1975), edited by Didier L. Goyvaerts and Geoffrey K. Pullum. A different explanation given by Jonathan B. Alcántara in "The Architecture of the English Lexicon" (1998) is that words like "athletic" and "episodic" actually end in a segment /ə/ that "is never allowed to surface, but will provide a final syllable" that explains the stress pattern of these words (3-114). In other words, the suffix spelled "ic" is in some way really /-icə/.)

There are other monosyllabic suffixes that behave similarly to *-ic,* such as the adjective suffix *-id,* the verb suffix *-ish,* and the noun suffix *-ule.* It has been observed that these (and also the disyllabic suffixes that commonly trigger trisyllabic shortening, like *-ity, -ify, -ular, -ual,* and according to Alcántara *-ible,* although I'm unsure if this suffix is actually a very consistent trigger of a short vowel in the preceding syllable) all start with high vowels (Alcántara A-310), but I'm not sure if this is significant in the way it might be taken to be; these endings are from Latin endings that contained short vowels (e.g. *-ĭcus, -ĭdus, -ŭlus, -ĭtās, -ĭfĭcāre, -ĭbĭlis, -ŭlāris, -ŭālis*) and non-high short vowels had a somewhat limited distribution in word-internal (not initial or final) open syllables in Latin due to processes of vowel reduction that turned other vowels into **ĭ** and **ŭ** in these contexts.