# monitoring pronounced /'mɑnəɹɪŋ/

Tags: american-english, formality, speech, phonology

I'd like to know the steps that lead to the pronunciation of *monitoring* as /'mɑnəɹɪŋ/.

min 0:44 in the following video

https://genius.com/videos/A-linguist-breaks-down-the-emotion-behind-young-thug-s-vocal-style?utm_source=home_video_series

Comment: Vowel length and nasality are important to capture if you're gonna try to represent fast speech variants phonetically. The /a/ should be long and nasalized; in addition, the /n/ is flapped.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I do feel like I hear a consonant before the [ɹ], but I can't offer more evidence than my ears because of a combination of lack of phonetics knowledge and laziness (I'm not going to try to analyze a spectrogram, because I don't know much about how to and I'm not going to study it just to post an answer to this question).

The phone [ɾ], present in standard accents of American English as conditioned allophone of /t/ and /d/, has a relatively "weak" articulation; while this does mean that it can sometimes be elided entirely (but still heard by most listeners due to the "[phonemic restoration effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_restoration_effect)"), it might also mean that you've just missed hearing it when it was actually phonetically present. I would guess that the closely following [ɹ] (also a relatively "weakly" articulated sound) could maybe also have some kind of masking effect.

I would transcribe the utterance as one of the following: ['mɑnəɾɹɪŋ], ['mɑnɪɾɹɪŋ], ['mɑnəɾɹ̩ɪŋ], ['mɑnɪɾɹ̩ɪŋ] (Actually, there's something else that John Lawler mentioned in a comment that I forgot about: rather than [n] (a nasal stop), technically the second consonant may be a nasal tap/flap, usually transcribed [ɾ̃].)

['mɑnəɾɹ̩]~['mɑnɪɾɹ̩] is a standard strong pronunciation of the verb  "monitor" in American English, so it doesn't take much to get to ['mɑnəɾɹɪŋ], just de-syllabification of the syllabic resonant [ɹ̩].

It's standard for original /t/ to be realized as [ɾ] in this context (intervocalic, directly following a stressed vowel and directly preceding a reduced vowel). See Wikipedia on [flapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping).

It's standard for original "weak" /ɪ/ to be realized as [ə] in American English; more precisely, it tends to be realized as the higher allophone of schwa, rather than the lower allophone that is usual word-finally (see [Exodus word pronounciation - Why it is different from spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/362679/77227) for more detailed discussion of this). However, some American English speakers do feel like they don't fully have this merger, or that the merged vowel is better transcribed as [ɪ] or [ɨ]. See Wikipedia on the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger).

Comment: I don't know how that's not just plain ['mɑnətɹiŋ] here. That's sure what it sounds like to me.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, I didn't hear a voiceless plosive, but it's possible that there was a brief one.

Comment: Thnx. The issue here is ɾ̃ vs n, yet I seem to hear exactly the one I am thinking of right at the moment