# When to use -ial and -al in forming adjectives, like pictorial and electoral

Tags: adjectives, orthography

I have some adjectives that have either [-ial](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ial) or [-al](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-al) in the end. Two duo suffixes are same in meaning.

**Words sufixed with -ial:**

> Luxor**ial**, pictor**ial**, advertor**ial**, editor**ial**,

**Words suffixed with -al:**

> Elector**al**, predoctor**al**, perichondr**al**, pastor**al**.

---

Analysis of their spelling pattern:

Why can't pastoral be spelled as pastorial, and electoral and perichondral as electorial and perichondrial, respectively?

Comment: My guess: *pictorial* is from Latin *pictorius*, which already has the *i* in there.  But *electoral* was formed within English, *elector* + *-al*.  I did not check your other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pronunciation is different for *-al* and *-ial* words

I don't know whether you meant for this to go without saying, but *-al* and *-ial* differ not only in spelling but also in pronunciation:

- The letter I in *-ial* often corresponds to an unstressed high vowel /i/ (or in some British accents, /ɪ/) or a glide /j/. Or it may represent a modification of a preceding consonant sound (*facial* is typically pronounced with /ʃ/, unlike the noun *face* which is pronounced with /s/).
- The stress in a word ending in *-ial* is always (or at least, almost always) on the immediately preceding syllable, whereas the stress of words ending in a consonant letter followed by *-al* is harder to predict based on the spelling (there are a few rules that cover particular subtypes of *-al* words; e.g. if there is a "heavy" consonant cluster before *-al,* as there is in *pericho**n.dr**al,* the stress tends to fall on the immediately preceding syllable, whereas [for words ending in *-ical,* the stress falls on the third-to-last syllable as a rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/303734/77227)).

### If the related noun contains I/Y, it's likely that the adjective will also

For some words ending in *-ial,* the letter I corresponds to an I or Y in the related noun. For example, *cran**i**al* and *cran**i**um,* *rad**i**al* and *rad**i**us,* *mercur**i**al* and *mercur**y**,* *arter**i**al* and *arter**y**, adversar**i**al* and *adversar**y***. (There is however an exceptional word *peripheral* that uses *-al* instead of *-ial* despite being derived from the noun *periphery* which ends in Y.)

### If the related noun ends in *-ce,* it's likely that the adjective will end in *-ial*

In Latinate English words, the ending *-ce* often can be traced back to earlier *-ci-* or *-ti-,* so many nouns ending in *-ce* have corresponding adjectives ending in *-cial* or *-tial.* Some examples: *face, facial; office, official; space, spatial; substance, substantial.*

### If the related noun doesn't contain I/Y or end in *-ce*, I don't know of a good rule for determining whether to use *-ial* or *-al*

For some *-ial* words, such as your example of *editorial,* there isn't an I in the related noun (*editor*). It is hard to say why we say *editorial* but *doctoral.* In fact, *doctorial* is not entirely nonexistent, although it's very uncommon. As far as I know, the fact that we usually say (and write) *doctoral* instead of *doctorial* is somewhat arbitrary.

Neither *-al* nor *-ial* is very productive as a way of forming new adjectives in modern English.